# Code working in IDE but not in Python 3.10

Tags: python, ide

My code seems works in my IDE but not in Python 3.10

I am trying to run this code:

```
from tkinter import Tk

file = open('raw.txt', 'w', encoding="utf-8")
file.write(str(Tk().clipboard_get()))
file.close()
```

It is supposed to write what is in the user's clipboard to a text file.
Whenever I run it in my IDE (I am using Wing), it runs perfectly fine. However, when I try to run it in Python 3.10 it closes the window and does not write the contents of my clipboard to `raw.txt`, so I assume it comes across an error.

As a side note, I have no idea what utf-8 encoding is. I began using it after I came across this error:

```
builtins.UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 5609-5610: character maps
```

and it began working in the IDE.
I tried removing the UTF-8 encoding and nothing changed.

Comment: Hey, few questions. One: Have you pip-installed Tkinter? Two: Did you print and check if the clipboard_get() gives you the desired content?

Comment: @Vaishali Yes I have installed Tkinter and I can easily print the desired content, the problem occurs when I attempt to write it into a text file

Answer (score 0):

In Tkinter, see if `selection_get()` works for you.

Instead of `clipboard_get()`, see if the `pyperclip` module works for you.

*Note:* many have asked about the challenges in using `pyperclip` here: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=pyperclip

Comment: I tried pyperclip and another module called clipboard and both had the same issue

Comment: @completeamateur Ah I see